# Closing a Screen Pinned activity

Tags: android, android-screen-pinning

I've an application that I allow the user to use only on a specific condition (let us call it 'X').

When user launches the application and 'X' is false, I finish() the application and hence the access to the application is blocked.
I did not consider one case while designing this - That is screen pinning.

If the user pins this application, and 'X' is false, the application shows an error alert. When the user closes this alert, finish() is not working as expected. The control stays in the same activity and the user can continue to use it.

It looks like finish() does not work when the application is pinned. Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.